# After normalizing a wavefunction I don't know how to calculate probability on an interval (-0.1 + 0.1)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

This is quite large homework where I 1st had to normalize the wavefunction $\psi = Axe^{-x^2/2a}$ and I got a constant $A=\sqrt{2/(a\sqrt{\pi a})}$.

How do I calculate the probability now for the interval  (-0.1nm , + 0.1nm) if $a=1nm^2$?

---

I first tried to calculate the normalisation factor but the units are weird... is this possible? Is most likely my normalisation factor wrong?

$$A=\sqrt{\frac{2}{1nm^2 \cdot \sqrt{\pi\cdot1nm^2}}}=1.06\frac{1}{nm\sqrt{nm}}$$

---

**EDIT:** After thinking again I decided to include the derivation of the normalisation factor $A$:

\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty A^2x^2 \exp\left[\tfrac{-x^2}{a}\right]dx = 1 = A^2\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \underbrace{x}_f\cdot \underbrace{x\exp\left[\tfrac{-x^2}{a}\right]}_{dg/dx} dx= \\
&=A^2\left[\smash{\underbrace{\left.x\left(-\tfrac{a}{2}\right)\exp\left[\tfrac{-x^2}{a}\right]\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}}_0}-\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\left(-\tfrac{a}{2}\right)\exp\left[\tfrac{-x^2}{a}\right]dx\right]=\\
&=\tfrac{A^2a}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[\tfrac{-x^2}{a}\right]dx = \tfrac{A^2a}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}\sqrt{a}\,dt = \tfrac{A^2a\sqrt{a}}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}dt = \frac{A^2a\sqrt{a}}{2}\sqrt{\pi}
\end{align}

Which means that:

\begin{align}
\frac{A^2a\sqrt{a}}{2}\sqrt{\pi} &= 1\\
A&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a\sqrt{a\pi}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your units are perfectly fine. In QM, the units of your wavefunction should be $1/\sqrt{length}$, which they are. The reason for these units is that probability is unitless and to get the probability, you integrate the square modulus of the wavefunction over x. Doing the unit analysis on that easily gives unitless.

---

Since $a$ is essentially one, and since it seems like you've correctly found $A$, you could drop the units and integrate $x$ from $-0.1$ to $0.1$.

Comment: But I have units $1/(nm \sqrt{nm})$. Take a closer look. This means i have a wrong $A$?

Comment: I decided to include my calculation of the normalisation factor in this question (under **EDIT**).

Comment: You normalization factor has units of $1/(nm\sqrt{nm})$ but it is multiplied by x, which would have units of nm, thus your wavefunction has the right units

Comment: Ok so I now calculated the normalisation factor $A=1.06/(nm\sqrt{nm})$. What follows? What I know is that i have to redo the integral with limits $\int\limits_{-0.1nm}^{+0.1nm}A^2x^2\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{a}\right]$ but if i do this i cannot evaluate the integral in the end to equal $\sqrt{\pi}$ and even the first part isn't $0$ (see my **EDIT**). This is where i am lost... What is the easiest way to do this? Do i really have to calculate allover again? I have tried and in the end i end up with an integral $\int_{-0.1nm}^{0.1nm} e^{-x^2/a}$ which I cannot solve...

Comment: You should probably do that integral numerically. If you're allowed to use Wolfram|Alpha, I'd use that. But it looks like you're doing it the right way

Comment: I did insert $\int_{-0.1nm}^{0.1nm} e^{-x^2/a}$ into Wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-0.1%7D%5E%7B0.1%7De%5E(-x%5E2%2F1)%20dx&t=crmtb01 What  got was result $0.1993/(nm\sqrt{nm})$. This is numericaly i understand. **But what about solving it analiticaly? Is this even possible?**

Comment: if you do it analytically, you end up with an error function (Erf), it's a valid mathematical function, but it usually indicates you should do it numerically. Don't forget the $A^2$

Comment: What do you mean with "don't forget $A^2$"?

Comment: 0.1993 is what you get before you multiply by the $A^2$ outside the integral

Comment: Total result is $0.224$ which equals $22.4\%$. This result differs from the one my professor got. She got $0.00075$ and this is very small. Who is most likely wrong here?

Comment: you, I got what your teacher got. Try typing the whole expressing into wolfram

Comment: Can you send me the link if you typed it already? This would also be nice so i could see how this is done properly. **EDIT:** I have noticed that links are weirdly edited here, so please post it in your edited anwser if possible.

Comment: no link, i use mathematica

Comment: If anyone else will ever reads this topic I will paste an input that I inserted into Wolfram Alpha to get the result $0.00075$. The input was: "**int_(-0.1)^(0.1) 1.06^2*x^2*e^(-x^2/1) dx**". And readers can find Wolfram alpha here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/